# Parsing Custom date time from lmStat in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm trying to parse the output from a licence manager program that gives me data in the following format:

user.name XSC181 XSC181 (v7.0) (xlicense/7570 1088), start Thu 2/20 9:21

I've cut this down to give me just the string "Thu 2/20 9:21" but am getting a formatexception when trying to use DateTime.ExactParse.  Does anyone know what format string I should be using?

```
public DateTime LicenceStartTime
    {
        get
        {
            var checkoutTime = Source.Substring(Source.LastIndexOf("start")).Replace("start", String.Empty);
            var format = "ddd M/dd h:mm";
            try
            {
                var result = DateTime.ParseExact(checkoutTime, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                return result;
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                return DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value you're trying to parse is `" Thu 2/20 9:21"` (notice the space in the first character). Change the line that takes the substring to the following:

```
var checkoutTime = Source.Substring(Source.LastIndexOf("start"))
    .Replace("start ", String.Empty);
```

And it should work.

Comment: +1 Nice catch, or add a space in front of the format